# Слить разные датафрейм в один

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Не могу слить разные датафрейм в один. Есть 4-ре датафрейма, файлы [тут](https://dropmefiles.com/tSnDL).

Открываю один из них:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('df3.csv')
del df['Unnamed: 0']
df
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может казаться, что они одинаковы, но нет, они могут быть любого размера и с пропусками по времени.
Соответственно хочу слить их по дате Date_temp и времени Time. Open1-High1-Low1-Close1,Open2-High2-Low2-Close2,Open3-High3-Low3-Close3,Open4-High4-Low4-Close4 будут из 4х файлов в новом df.

Пробую так `df = df3.merge(df2, how="left")`, да и вообще по-разному пробовал — получаются какие-то пропуски или каша.

И если в каком то датафрейме будут пустые значения на какие то минуты, то они должны заполниться предыдущим первым значением из датафрейм. Знаю что это делается как `.fillna()`

Пример:

```
Если будет в столбце как слева, то делаем как пример справа:

Open4   >>>   Open4
3.45    >>>   3.45   
NA      >>>   3.45 
NA      >>>   3.45 
4.42    >>>   4.42 
3.81    >>>   3.81
```

Comment: @gevd1 Вы понимаете, что диапазон дат в этих датафреймах такой: `[2018-07-27 - 2021-12-04, 2021-11-23 - 2021-12-04, 2021-11-03 - 2021-12-04, 2021-11-03 - 2021-12-04]`. Т.е. диапазон дат второго фрейма - это 10 дней, а первого фрейма - это 3,5 года! Каким чудом вы хотите получить данные для второго фрейма в том же диапазоне, что у первого фрейма, если их там физически нет? Или вы предлагаете вообще не смотреть на даты, даты там просто так, от балды написаны, нужно смотреть на индексы?

Answer (score 3):

Слить датафреймы вместе можно так:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

data_frames = [pd.read_csv(f'df{i}.csv', index_col=0) for i in range(1,5)]
df_merged = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right, on=['Date_temp','Time'], how='outer'), data_frames)
df_merged = df_merged.sort_values(['Date_temp','Time']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Обратите внимание на тип слияния `outer` и колонки, по которым я делаю слияние. Но в результате там будет очень много пропусков, в том числе в начале, так просто через `ffill` или `bfill` вы их не заполните.

P.S. Добавил сортировку объединённого датафрейма по дате-времени, чтобы было меньше вопросов к графикам и т.д.

P.P.S. Для понимания ситуации с графиками:

```
df_merged[[c for c in df_merged.columns if c.startswith('Close')]].plot();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные вообще толком не пересекаются. Совпадают только `Close3` и `Close4` целиком, из-за этого графика `Close3` вообще не видно. И это индексы, а не даты! В равномерном графике по датам данные последних 3-х фреймов были бы сконденсированы в микроскопическом отрезке справа.

Comment: к сожаление по факту получается дикая каша в данных :)

Comment: @gevd1 Ну так даты разные в разных датафреймах, что же вы хотите? Данные объединяются по датам, даты не сильно пересекаются. Если хотите, могу это перепроверить

Comment: имею ввиду там графики на оригинал вообще не похожи, без учета дыр

Comment: Я посмотрел, у вас в df2,df3,df4 данные за самый конец 2021 года, а в df1 у вас данные с 2018 года до конца 2021, и как вы эти данные предлагаете объединять?

Comment: @gevd1, вы можете внятно объяснить чем именно вас не устраивает результат объединения и что значит "столбцы не похожи на оригинал"?

Comment: @MaxU, ну как внятно :) понимаете, если построить график оригинального значения скажем Close4 и того Close4 который будет при объединении - это разные графики. Тоесть вооооооообще бредятина выходит. Ну тоесть это не работает нормально

Comment: @gevd1, я только что начертил отдельно график `df4["Close4"]` и `df_merged["Close4"]` - получились одинаковые графики - разница только в том что у второго графика есть пропуски

Comment: @gevd1 А вы сделайте `.sort_values(['Date_temp','Time']).reset_index(drop=True)` перед отрисовкой, если вы прям через `df.plot()` рисуете, и графики практически совпадут. Там просто индексы не в том порядке.

Comment: @gevd1 А вы из исходных датафреймов рисовали Close3 и Close4? Они и есть одинаковые ;)  Повторюсь - не забывайте сортировать по датам. По умолчанию датафрейм рисуется по сортировке индекса! А индекс может быть отсортирован как угодно, в том числе в исходных датафреймах! И `plt.plot` тоже не в курсе, что должно быть по оси `x`, откуда ему знать правильную сортировку последовательности данных в датафрейме.

Comment: @gevd1, а сложно было в вопросе указать как именно вы чертите графики?? Каша у вас из-за того, что вы кашу чертите. `plt.plot(df_merged['Close3'])` - использует значения 0,..,N-1 в качестве значений по оси `X`. Если у вас в одном векторе 3000  значений, а в другом 7080 значений, то графики не будут совпадать от слова "совсем". Используйте дату и время в качестве значений по оси `X` и все будет правильно работать - пример у меня в ответе

Answer (score 3):

Похоже "проблема" автора в недопонимании того, как строятся графики и что значения по оси `X` - также важны как значения по оси `Y`.

Сначала я бы предложил создать один столбец - с датой и временем вместо двух строковых столбцов:

```
from pathlib import Path

def parse_data(filename: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(filename, 
                       parse_dates={"Date": ["Date_temp", "Time"]}, 
                       usecols=range(1,8), 
                       index_col="Date")

p = Path(".")

df = pd.concat([parse_data(f) for f in p.glob("df*.csv")], axis=1)
```

С вашими данными при построении графиков в качестве значений по оси `X` нужно указывать значения даты и времени:

---

графики:

```
df4 = parse_data("df4.csv")

df4.plot(y="Close4")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и тот же "Close4" но из объединенного фрейма:

```
df.plot(y="Close4")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: объясните этот график. https://dropmefiles.com/3t0KN. вверху оригинал. ниже применение вашего кода.

Comment: @gevd1, уже [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357387/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd/1357438#comment2408876_1357403) все объяснил

Comment: ваш код мне объяснил на примере который скинул выше. Можно хоть через черную материю сортировать, код портит данные, код не пригоден и все. Как хотите

Comment: @gevd1 Ну вы же понимаете, что в объединённом датафрейме появляются даты/время, которых нет в одних датафреймах, но есть в других? В этих местах и есть разрывы. Причём, даже если их заполнить через `ffill`, то графики будут разные! Потому что одно дело провести прямую из `(x1,y1)` в `(x2,y2)` и другое дело прямая из `(x1,y1)` в `(x1',y1)`, а потом из `(x1',y1)` в `(x2,y2)`, это будут не одинаковые графики.

Comment: @gevd1, вы попробуйте для начала не сравнивать "апельсины со свиньями" - прочитайте `df2` используя мою функцию - `df2 = parse_data("df2.csv")` потом начертите график, потом подумайте...)